# Simplicial set such that its geometric realization is a circle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, geometric-realization

I got confused with the definition of a simplicial set and its geometric realization. Is it correct that if I take the following simplicial set then its geometric realization will be a circle?

$X_0=\{a_0,b_0\}$, $X_n=\{a_n\}$ for $0<n$. All the maps are constant with image $a_i$ s.t. $0\leq i$.

Comment: This does not define a simplicial set if $b_0 \neq a_0$. It must be the case that $f_i \circ d_i = id$ where $f_i$ is the $i$-th face map and $d_i$ is the $i$-th degeneracy map. Then if you set $i=0$ and plug in $b_0$ you get that  $b_0 =  f_0 \circ d_0 (b_0) = f_0(a_1) = a_0$. A contradiciton.

Answer (score 1):

What might help you construct examples is these objects that I can't for the life of me remember what they are called. Anyway, of your simplex category $\Delta$ you have a subcategory with the same objects but morphisms are those morphisms which are injective in $\Delta$. This category is called $\Delta_+$.

You have an inclusion $\Delta_+ \rightarrow \Delta$, so a restriction functor $[\Delta^{op},\textbf{Set}] \rightarrow [\Delta_+^{op},\textbf{Set}]$. This restriction functor has a left adjoint $L$ which basically takes a functor $\Delta_+^{op} \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ and adjoins a bunch of degenerate simplices to make it a simplicial set.

Then if you consider for instance $X:\Delta_+^{op} \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ given by $X_0=\{p\}$, $X_1=\{s\}$ and $X_n = \emptyset$ else this does indeed define a functor letting morphisms in $\Delta^{op}_+$ get taken to the only possible ones. You should picture $X$ as a circle because you have one $0$-simplex that you attach both ends of a $1$-simplex to. This avoids the problem of having to explicitly define the degenerate simplices.

You can also show that if we define geometric realization of a functor $Y:\Delta_+^{op} \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ in the same way we define geometric realization of simplicial sets that $\mid Y \mid \cong \mid LY \mid$ for all $Y$, they are homotopy equivalent. This is because $LY$ is just $Y$ with a bunch of degenerate simplices attached so when taking geometric realization you can squish all of these simplices down and end up with a homotopy equivalence. Anyway you can easily show that $\mid X \mid = S^1$ and thus $\mid LX \mid \cong S^1$.

It is not possible to find a simplicial set $S$ and a homeomorphism $\mid S\mid \rightarrow S^1$ since $S$ will always contain degenerate simplices in a high dimension so the best you can do is homotopy equivalence.

Please, if I get too carried away here tell me. I'm happy to explain in a more down to earth manner.

Comment: This isn’t correct. Every simplicial complex is realized homeomorphically. You take the realization of the category of simplices. Degenerate simplices simply don’t affect the realization. You may be thinking of fat geometric realization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was helpful. But I am still curious about a realization of simplex category $\Delta$ instead of $\Delta_+$

Comment: @ConnorMalin, I'm not talking about simplicial complexes, I'm talking about simplicial sets and is it not correct that you include the degenerate simplices in the realization aswell as the non-degenerate ones?

Comment: @whoami using the left adjoint you can get simplicial sets from functors $\Delta_+ ^{op} \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ whose geometric realization is homotopy equivalent to the (easier to compute) geometric realization of the original functor $\Delta_+ ^{op} \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$

Comment: @NoelLundström You can equivalently define the realization as either a quotient of all the simplices or as a quotient of just the nondegenerate simplices, but in the first just like you should quotient out by face maps you should also quotient out by degeneracy maps. This results in all degenerate simplices being collapsed.

Comment: @ConnorMalin, Interesting, I guess I'll have to review what I thought I knew a bit then